# Angular JS - Text boxes are not updating in Isolated Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my JS file:

```
var app=angular.module("isolateScope",[]);

app.controller("attrScope",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.gem="ruby";    
}]);

app.directive("diffScope",function(){
   return{
       scope:{
           gemType:'@',
           twoWay:'=',
       },
       //template:'@scope:<input type="text" ng-model="gemType"/><br/><label>=Scope</label><input type="text" ng-model="twoWay"/>'
   } 
});
```

In My HTML File:

```
 <div ng-controller="attrScope">
        <input type="text" ng-model="gem" />
        <div class="panel-group">
            <diff-scope gem-type="{{gem}}" two-way="gem">
                @scope:<input type="text" ng-model="gemType"/><br/><label>=Scope</label><input type="text" ng-model="twoWay"/>
                </diff-scope>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But child Textboxes are not updating when parent textbox is typed nor it is loading with the value from parent textbox?

Comment: can you add fiddle for this?

Comment: @alexey https://plnkr.co/edit/PT4FqiyasB8L2jlI1opC?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your template in html.
You have to use `ng-transclude` and add the isolated scope of the directive to the transclusion in link and add that transcludedElement with isolated scope to your directive element.

There is a very good description in this [blog post](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/) about it.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nseh54ch/).

```js
var app = angular.module("isolatedScopeApp", []);

app.controller("attrScope", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.gem = "ruby";
  }
]);

app.directive("diffScope", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      gemType: '@',
      twoWay: '=',
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
        element.append(clone);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="attrScope" ng-app="isolatedScopeApp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="gem" />
  <div class="panel-group">
    <diff-scope gem-type="{{gem}}" two-way="gem">
      @scope:
      <input type="text" ng-model="gemType" />
      <br/>
      <label>=Scope</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="twoWay" />
    </diff-scope>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't define the template inside the html you use your directive in as you did. In this case, you must use [transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude), that will let you define html content in both directive's template *and* child elements in your directive.

When you define your directive, you must specify either the `template` or the `templateUrl` property (as you did, but commented it out). Namely in this template your scope attributes will get passed and become available.

Check out [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/TnkAR0KiOE65e7eK95aG?p=preview) fork of your plunker with the working solution.